# Telerik-grid paging and sorting when using an external data source

Tags: asp.net, sorting, telerik, paging, telerik-grid

I am experimenting with using an external data source with a Telerik Grid using their Twitter search sample as my guide

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/externalservicetwitter

I have got their sample running but cannot get paging and sorting to work.

In the sample they set-up the grid server side using the code

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<TwitterItem>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(o => { }).Title("Author").Width(100);
        columns.Template(o => { }).Title("Avatar").Width(80);
        columns.Bound(o => o.text).Title("Post");
    })
    .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnDataBinding("onDataBinding")
        .OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound")
    )
    .Scrollable(scrolling=>scrolling.Height(400)))
```

So I added .Pageable and .Sortable to the construct like in the other samples but this seems to make no difference

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<TwitterItem>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(o => { }).Title("Author").Width(100);
        columns.Template(o => { }).Title("Avatar").Width(80);
        columns.Bound(o => o.text).Title("Post");
    })
    .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnDataBinding("onDataBinding")
        .OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound")
    )
    .Scrollable(scrolling=>scrolling.Height(400))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
```

)

Should this be working?  Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: When I try this with .Pageable added, I get the paging status bar at the bottom, but the animated gif in the bottom left corner keeps spinning like the data has not finished loading. And the paging status text says, "Displaying items 0 - 0 of 0". When I try with .Sortable added, the Post column acts like it is sorting, but doesn't actually sort. The Author and Avatar columns don't sort because they are Template columns. It seems that because of the way the data loads, there is a problem with paging and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.
My challenge is that the users want to retreive repeatedly for different criteria and they expect the results to accumulate in the grid until they clear the grid.  I am building this capability.  I got the accumulation to work, but along the way something is causing the "Displaying items 0 - 0 of 0".
This question has been sitting out here for a long time.  It makes me feel discouraged.
My theory is that the custom binding messes up the other settings.
Joe